# Is it possible to write an if statement for a PHP meta description?

Tags: php, web, meta

I wanted to know if it was possible to write an if statement for an PHP meta description.

I know the basic description is this

```
<meta name="description" content=<?php echo e($this->video['title']); ?>
```

I am asking if it is possible to make an if statement to check if the title is blank or something like that.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: I mean if there is no title for the current page then the if statement would equal the "quote" I put there after the if statement.

Comment: *"I wanted to know if it was possible to write an if statement for an php meta description."* - Have you tried it? Betch'ya didn't ;-)

Comment: Where is your title?  `if (empty($title)) ...`

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking about **possibilities** and **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results. [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Best to consult with Code Fetchers Anonymous. They meet up every Friday night. Bring coffee, am sure nobody'll bring any.

Comment: You've missed off the quote marks around that title, and the tag needs closing with a `/>` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your question is but it may be what you are looking for:

```
if(e($this->video['title'])!=""){//Checking if title is not blank 
?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo e($this->video['title']); ?>"><?php }?>
```